# My entry results are not consistently alphabetized

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query, query-posts

I have a specific query that shows all results. Those results are ALMOST alphabetized except for one entry.

I also have a menu that allows you to see those entries based on tax term. When you do this the results are no longer alphabetized AT ALL.

How do I keep them alphabetized?

Go here and then click on “Los Angeles” in the left hand menu. It should be alphabetized by first name. It is not.
http://aug4th.com/steinberg.com/people/

It's a page that loads a custom WP_query

Page:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$temp =  $query;
$query = null;

$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
) );

$query -> query('post_type=people&posts_per_page=400&orderby=name&order=ASC&post_status=publish'.'&paged='.$paged);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<div id="primary" class="container-fluid border-left archive-articles content-area">
        <?php get_template_part('content', 'people-menu'); ?>

        <div class="archive-content">
            <main id="main" class="row site-main" role="main">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
                         $query->the_post(); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'people' ); ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php $query = null; $query = $temp; ?>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Menu on left hand side:

```
<div class="work-menu">
    <ul class="news-item_cat-list nav-cat-list--fixed">
        <li>
            <a href="people">All</a>
        </li>
        <?php $taxonomy = 'studio';
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); 

        if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
        ?>

        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php endif;?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The `name` refers to the slug of the post, so the name of the first entry is `4808-2`. What do you get if  you order by `title`

Comment: @czerspalace That fixes the results for "All". Didn't notice that slug. However it doesn't fix the other categories which are showing based on most recently published.

Comment: Those look like they are from an archive template. Do you have an `archive-studio.php` file in your theme folder?

Comment: I don't have an archive page for that tax, no. I have a regular page that loads a template file.

Comment: Do you have an `archive.php`? You should review the query on that page, or copy that file to `archive-studio.php` and then alter the query